# Qual a função do operador " | " dentro do catch?

Tags: java, exceção, operadores, try-catch

Li que `||` (OR) é para operações booleanas e `|` (Bitwise operation) para operações de bits. Qual a sua função dentro de um **catch com múltiplas exceptions**, então? Digo, sei que elimina código duplicado mas sempre o considerei como um OR booleano.

Exemplo

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Se houver alguma `IOException` **OU** `SQLException` o laço é executado.

Comment: Não sei responder, mas eu arriscaria dizer que é apenas um artifício sintático, e não um *operador* como `|` ou `||`. Afinal, não são valores que estão sendo combinados, e sim tipos (tipos mesmo, não representações de tipos, como instâncias de `Class` etc). De modo que as regras usuais da linguagem para operadores não se aplicam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em java SE 7 ou superior um único block de `catch` pode lidar com mais de um tipo de exceção, para isso você deve especificar os tipos de exceção que quer capturar e separá-los por um pipe `|`, exemplo:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Neste caso o pipe não é um operador lógico e sim uma sintaxe do recurso.

Em versões anteriores do Java tínhamos que tratar as exceções de forma individual ou utilizar uma classe mais abrangente  (`Exception`, por exemplo) para capturar lançamentos de todas as possíveis exceções, com este recurso podemos transformar, por exemplo:

**Este código**

```
try {
    System.out.println(10 / 0);
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**Neste**

```
try {
    System.out.println(10 / 0);
} catch (ArithmeticException | IllegalArgumentException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

OBS: A variável declarada no `catch` é sempre `final`, ou seja não podemos atribuir nenhum valor à ela.

**Fonte: [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)**

Answer (score 7):

Esta é uma feature que foi introduzida a partir do Java 7. Você pode usar ela para remover possíveis trechos de catch's duplicados. Ex:

```
catch (IOException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
}
```

por:

```
catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

[Você pode ver uma explicação completa neste link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Answer (score 3):

O símbolo serve exatamente para o que você supôs, é como um "OU". Ele serve para você capturar múltiplas exceções em um único bloco `catch`, ao invés de fazer um `catch` para cada exceção. Por exemplo, isso:

```
try {
  // Código a executar
} catch (ExceptionType1 name) {
  // Código a executar quando uma exceção do tipo "ExceptionType1" for disparada
} catch (ExceptionType2 name) {
  // Código a executar quando uma exceção do tipo "ExceptionType2" for disparada
}
```

Pode ser reduzido para isso:

```
try {
  // Código a executar
} catch (ExceptionType1|ExceptionType2 name) {
  // Código a executar quando uma exceção do tipo "ExceptionType1" ou "ExceptionType2" for disparada
}
```

### Mas por que não usar o "||"?

Se formos analisar, o `|` e o `||` tem a mesma função: verificar múltiplas condições de uma vez ("se `condição1` for X ou `condição2` for Y ou `condição3` for Z", etc). Porém há uma pequena diferença. O `||` é um **operador lógico**, serve para como já foi dito verificarmos diversas condições em uma **estrutura condicional**. Porém o código dentro do `catch` *não* é uma condição, logo, o `||` não toma a função de "ou condicional".

### Referência

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde, não tenho muita experiência, mas acho que vc poderia colocar dois catch...
no SQL o que vc esta querendo fazer? Seria a conexão?

```
catch (IOException ex1) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Erro ao Conectar ", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu a pergunta. Isso que está sendo mostrado é sintaxe válida, [suportada a partir da versão 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html), mas está correta. O que a AP pediu foi uma explicação a respeito da mesma, e não uma alternativa para ela.